# How to change uncategorized Data category in power Bi

Tags: powerbi

We have a dataset forms coming from a third party application which we want to integrate in power bi. So far we have connected it to power bi web and integrated the table from dataset now the problem is we have a column named gallery_media and it shows image URL instead of image we want to get image or image thumbnail instead of URL how do we achieve this?
I have looked online for a solution and found that if i change the data category to image URL the table will show image instead of url but the option is greyed out. Please help me in this?

[image]